# Python pandas: oposite of pandas.Series.str.match

Tags: python, pandas

How to Determine if each string in a column does not start with a match of a regular expression.

I need to check when a Column does NOT equal a string.

I've found:

```
pandas.Series.str.match
```

And it is almost what I need, but I want to get True when the string is NOT a match

Comment: Just add a tilde before it like this `~df['col'].str.contains("Hello")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `pd.Series.str.startswith`

```
df_sub = df[~df['col'].str.startswith('your str')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just negate the mask returned by `str.contains`:

```
~df['col'].str.contains("Your string")
```